# Error al crear un nuevo proyecto en Android Studio 3.5.3 de tipo Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, navigationview

Tengo un error al crear un nuevo proyecto en Android Studio 3.5.3 de tipo Navigation Drawer Activity. Los errores son los siguientes:

> -ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0 Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app
>
> -ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0 Show in Project
>   Structure dialog Affected Modules: app
>
> -ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0 Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app
>
> -ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0 Show in Project
>   Structure dialog Affected Modules: app

Al darle Sync al gradle salen esos errores aneriormente expuestos

**Mi configuracion en el archivo build.grade es la siguiente:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cu.rogel.elmensajero"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Sigue estos pasos para arreglar el primer error [Link](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) Para lo demás no se si esto te pueda servir [Link2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation)

Answer (score -1):

Para arreglar el primer error abre el archivo build.gradle para su aplicación y agrega esta parte de código:

```
allprojects {
 repositories {
  google()
  jcenter()
 }
}
```

Para lo demás no se si esto te pueda servir

```
  def nav_version = "2.1.0"
  // Java language implementation
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```